# SQL wont import because the data will be truncated. How do get it to just cut the string off at 16 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import, truncate

I need to import a `.CSV` file into a SQL Server table. In the table, one of the columns is of datatype `varchar(16)`, but in the `.CSV` Excel file, most of the entries in that column are 25 characters or more. I need SQL Server to just cut the string off at 16 characters and import that. How to I do this? I have no idea how to even start to code this

I import this into a table using the AnySQL Maestro import wizard by

1. right clicking the table
2. clicking data management
3. clicking import
4. selecting `.csv` as the file type
5. selecting which columns from the `.csv` match up with which columns in the sql table
6. clicking OK.

If the field in the `.csv` was the right size, there would be no issue importing

Comment: How are you importing this? Using your own custom code (then please **show it!**) ? With SSIS (Integration Services) ? Something else??

Comment: edited. see 2 new paragraphs

Comment: Why not create a new column in Excel which contains the first 16 characters from the column you want to import???   Or add a column to the table large enough to hold the field, they run an update statement to move the substring from that field to the actual target field

Comment: Check the AnySQL Maestro help / documentation / web site to see if there's any way to limit the number of characters being imported - this is really a **tool-specific** issue that has nothing to do with SQL Server per se .... if you can't find anything in their docs or on their web site - send the AnySQL guys a support request .....

Comment: because im not the one who has to import the table, and numerous .csv files have to be imported every day. each of these .csv files was originally exported from crystal reports. so creating a new column in excel is too time consuming and not productive. if the person importing this could just run a query before importing that would allow what im asking, that would be awsome

Comment: If AnySQL Maestro can't limit the number of characters being imported, you might just need to do a two-step process: **(1)** import your Excel `.csv` file into a temporary staging table (possibly using `BULK INSERT` for top performance), and then **(2)** update/insert relevant rows into the target table from the staging table, trimming off strings that are too long in the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution

1. Open your .CSV file with Excel.
2. In Excel keep first 16 characters and remove others (search left function)
3. Use SQL Server Management Studio to import data from Excel file